# Converting a Cucumber scenario DataTable (HashMap) to method calls

Tags: java, reflection, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am creating an acceptance test framework for an application that accepts XML files (with up to hundreds of fields) using Cucumber(-JVM), Junit, Java 8. I have created a library that serializes POJOs to XML with a lot of classes using the Builder interfaces (to avoid having dozens of constructors and to have a declarative API of sorts), i.e.:

```
new Form.Builder
    .setThisField(withThis)
    .setThatField(withThat)
    .build();
```

I made this library because I want to generate valid XML files dynamically in my tests. I want my cucumber scenarios to read like English, so I decided to use data tables instead of writing something like:

```
Given I have a form with x field
and with y field
and with z field
and ...
```

With 50 different 'and' lines. So they look like this:

```
Given that I have Form B101 with the following fields:
  | X Field        | X Value         |
  | Y Field        | Y Value         |
  | Z Field        | Z Value         |
```

The Problem:

I want the keys in the cucumber data table (which is turned into a HashMap) to map to method names for my builder pattern. At first I thought using lambdas and method references may let me accomplish this, but I have yet to find a way.

So my next thought was reflection. I decided to store a mapping from a Cucumber Data table key to a method name in a properties file like:

```
//mapping.properties
X\ Field = setXField 
// the \ after X is to escape the space
```

I have run into a problem though: some of the fields in the cucumber data table map to deeply nested fields (due to the XML schema) in my XML Data binding library. So for example:

"X Field" is nested within A Field. So in my test method I need to do:

```
AField aField = new AField(new XField());
```

But with reflection in java, you need to know the parameter data types before the fact (or so I think). For example, if I want to find out what parameter types are associated with a method:

```
Class[] paramString = new Class[1];
paramString[0] = AField.class;
// So I need to know before the fact that methodName (below) has a parameter
// of type AField in order to .... get the parameter types of methodName.


// this is legal because a method with methodName exists and it takes
// one parameter with type AField.
Class[] parameterTypes = 
  formB.getClass().getMethod(methodName, paramString).getParameterTypes();

// this is not legal. no method named methodName which doesn't 
// take parameters exists
Class[] parameterTypes = 
  formB.getClass().getMethod(methodName).getParameterTypes();
```

I'm sure I could find a workaround for this, but ultimately it seems like I'm going down a 'hacky' path. Is there a better way to approach this problem? Or am I on the 'correct' path?

Comment: You talk a o lot about your implementation. Are you able to share more about your problem? I get the feeling that you are using Cucumber in a way it isn't good at. But a concrete example would be nice to maybe understand more about your goal.

Comment: @ThomasSundberg By problem do you mean the application I am testing? Essentially I am testing a web service which will accept XML files. I built a tool to generate xml files dynamically. Some of these XML files have 125+ fields, with business rules that I need to test on, say, 25 different fields. So I need to express the data I want in each XML file in cucumber. I thought a data table would be the most sensible solution rather than having either a) 100 lines in a cucumber scenario b) a hacky short-hand to express the values of 100 fields.

Comment: @ThomasSundberg Additionally, I cannot change the application to break up the XML files into smaller, sub-XML files.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of incurring a moderator's wrath (explicit answers are preferred to links), I will point you to this [link](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2014/06/30/cucumber-data-tables).  To get the List to a HashMap consider [this]

**EDIT**

Here is an extract of the relevant part from the referenced link.

Convert a two column table to a Map.

```
Feature: Cucumber can convert a Gherkin table to a map.
  This an example of a simple price list.

  Scenario: A price list can be represented as price per item
    Given the price list for a coffee shop
      | coffee | 1 |
      | donut  | 2 |
    When I order 1 coffee and 1 donut
    Then should I pay 3
```

And the code:

```
package se.thinkcode.steps;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

import java.util.Map;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class SimplePriceList {
    private Map<String, Integer> priceList;
    private int totalSum;

    @Given("^the price list for a coffee shop$")
    public void the_price_list_for_a_coffee_shop(Map<String, Integer> priceList) throws Throwable {
        this.priceList = priceList;
    }

    @When("^I order (\\d+) (.*) and (\\d+) (.*)$")
    public void i_order_coffee_and_donut(int numberOfFirstItems, String firstItem,
           int numberOfSecondItems, String secondItem) throws Throwable {

        int firstPrice = priceList.get(firstItem);
        int secondPrice = priceList.get(secondItem);

        totalSum += firstPrice * numberOfFirstItems;
        totalSum += secondPrice * numberOfSecondItems;
    }

    @Then("^should I pay (\\d+)$")
    public void should_I_pay(int expectedCost) throws Throwable {
        assertThat(totalSum, is(expectedCost));
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree with MikeJRamsey56. BeanUtils are a "better" way to convert the Map<String, Object> you get to your data-structure.

Comment: I agree, with you - it's clearly a bad answer by SO standards.  It's "link only" answer and you should include the gist of the destination page into your answer - or it could be closed.

Comment: @AleksG I cry "uncle!".  Thank you for prompting me to improve the answer. I was too busy at the time and just wanted to give the OP a clue.  Probably should have been a comment back then.

Comment: Very clean answer .. unlike the question itself :)